# Move camera around player while facing player

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

My player has the following hierarchy:

```
Hero (GameObject)
      Model (child of "Hero", centered at 0-0-0)
      Camera (child of "Hero")
```

The camera should be allowed to

```
- change its position around the Model in a circle ("rotate around the 
  center")
- rotate so that it always faces the Model
- move up and down
- move nearer and further from / to the Model
```

I know how to do that using Quaternions, but as I'm doing this in a coroutine and using Lerp, I found myself in situations where the camera would get right through the model as this was the shortest path between the destination and the target vector.

I would now like to use pure angles (Sin and Cos), preferrably without LookAt.
Can somebody share how I would position and rotate the camera according to the angle, perhaps even taking a camera height variable into account as the camera should also be able to move up and down, still facing the player?

That would be the bomb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have normalized vector from hero towards camera. Rotate the vector. Place camera at multiplied vector by range(distance). Rotate camera towards hero. Basically rotation around is placing object at the same distance but moving that object in some direction.

[Transform.RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Basically point - is hero position, axis is usually up, if your hero is in vertical position, and angle.

```
Camera.transform.RotateAround(hero.position, Vector3.up, rotationAngle * rotationSpeed);
```

[Result reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX1XmeI6zy4) - basically this is how I made planets rotate around star. You can access the whole project via link under video.

```
public void RotateAround(Transform transform)
{
    this.transform.RotateAround(transform.position, this._rotationAxis, this._rotationSpeed);
}

private void Update()
{
    this.RotateAround(this._star);
}

private void Awake()
{
    this._rotationAxis = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f) * (this.transform.position - this._star.position).normalized;
}
```

If you want to do it manually you can just store rotation angle, and change it. Using this method you can calculate the vector. Though, it's more for Top-Down, you will have to modify the method to suit your needs.

```
public static Vector3 GetDirectionFromAngle(float angleInDegrees, float localRotationAngle = 0)
{
    angleInDegrees += localRotationAngle;
    return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0, Mathf.Cos(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's getting interesting where you left off... Could you perhaps elaborate the "manual" approach? Because that's what I'm fighting with. RotateAround doesn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: I have also added 2 objectives to the post to make it understood why RotateAround wouldn't help me.

Comment: @tmighty zoom - you change the range of the camera, you can make it work with `RotateAround` (it's basically the same thing that doing this manually, it just makes all the calculations based on parameters). Same can be said for moving up or down, you can both `RotateAround` on horizontal and vertical axis. Look at how I calculate rotation axis in Awake. Basically you need to figure out how to change the rotation axis along the way when you are rotating vertically and horizontally, order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @tmighty About manual approach - I am not very good with math to give a solution right away, it may take a lot of effort and testing to make it work. It would even be harder without `RotateAround` for me personally.

Comment: Good to know that I'm not the only one having problems with this. :-)

Comment: @tmighty basically what rotation axis is - a perpendicular vector - in order for it to rotate properly you need that vector to be aligned perpendicularly with vector from hero to camera to get the desired result. Basically, calculate the vector from hero to camera, rotate it 90 degrees. And then you can rotate around that vector. By rotating on some axis, you just recalculate all things including vector from hero to camera, and get new axis to rotate on another plane. It's a bit similar calculation to `Awake`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm fighting with this since 3 days, I'm really lost at it.

Comment: @tmighty I haven't done it till now (rotation around) :) And I have been in gamedev for 4 years. Rotation is complicated topic. I basically abandoned it and focused on strategy/top-down games that don't require it and which I prefer playing more. But once I spent 2 weeks just developing 1 simple attribute until I created extensions that I needed that have reflection in them for Editor code. Don't give up if you really need it. Or try to focus on something different and learn math along the way.